# Java. gif to Image[]

Tags: java, изображения, gif

Есть ли способ на java разложить *.gif на `image[]` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот так вы получите сырые кадры из `gif`, однако они будут содержать только дельты между кадрами:

```
 static List<BufferedImage> getFramesRaw(File gif) throws IOException {
    List<BufferedImage> frames = new ArrayList<>();
    ImageReader ir = new GIFImageReader(new GIFImageReaderSpi());
    ir.setInput(ImageIO.createImageInputStream(gif));
    for(int i = 0; i < ir.getNumImages(true); i++)
        frames.add(ir.read(i));
    return frames;
}
```

И вот примерно так их можно склеить в целые картинки:

```
static List<BufferedImage> getFrames(File gif) throws IOException {
    List<BufferedImage> copies = new ArrayList<>();
    List<BufferedImage> frames = getFramesRaw(gif);
    copies.add(frames.remove(0));
    for (BufferedImage frame : frames) {
        BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(copies.get(0).getWidth(),
                copies.get(0).getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        Graphics g = img.getGraphics();
        g.drawImage(copies.get(copies.size()-1),0,0,null);
        g.drawImage(frame,0,0,null);
        copies.add(img);
    }
    return copies;
}
```

Проверено на этой гифке

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

PS: насколько мне известно формат поддерживает экзотические ситуации и ухищрения, например когда кадры разного размера, код выше этого не учитывает..